# How can I join a list of employees and genders using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have retrieve a list of employees. my employee class columns(employeeId, lastname, genderid)

```
 List<m_employees> Items = new List<m_employees>
                    {
                        new m_employees{ employeeid = 1, lastname = "mike", genderid = 1 },
                        new m_employees{ employeeid = 2, lastname = "jeni", genderid = 2 }
                    };
```

then i have my gender class columns (id, title)

```
    List<m_genders> genders = new List<m_genders>
                {
                    new m_genders{ id = 1, title = "Male" },
                    new m_genders{ id = 2, title = "Female" }
                };

//then i tried joining the retrieved list of employees to the genders

var x = from emp in Items
                    join sex in genders
                    on emp.genderid equals sex.id
                    into a from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty(new m_genders())
                    select new
                    {
                        emp.lastname,
                        emp.genderid,
                        sex = b.title
                    };
```

red error line is showing to the keyword join and says "the type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect..."

how can i join them properly?

Comment: done. it is just a list of employees

Comment: post m_employees and m_genders classes, please.

Comment: your code works fine ! check it out here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7geOVL

Comment: The error message tells you that `m_genders.id` and `m_employees.genderid` are not compatible types. Since that's not the case above i'm pretty sure that this sample code is not the same as the real code. Maybe you are using int for one and string for the other. Then you either have to change that or use `int.Parse` or `int.ToString` to make them compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because types emp.genderid, sex.id are different and you need to cast or convert them explicitly like that:

```
(int)emp.genderid equals sex.id
```

I was able to reproduce the error with the following class definition:

```
class m_genders
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }

}

class employee
{
   public int id;
   public uint genderid;
   public string lastname { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: wow! you got it! you're right!! m_genders.id is uint by default since it is the primary key and auto incremented from the genders table

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, the code work without any problem :

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public class m_genders
    {
        public int id;
        public string title;
    }

    public class m_employees
    {
        public int employeeid { get; set; }
        public int genderid { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }

    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<m_genders> genders = new List<m_genders>
            {
                new m_genders {id = 1, title = "Male"},
                new m_genders {id = 2, title = "Female"}
            };

            List<m_employees> Items = new List<m_employees>
            {
                new m_employees{ employeeid = 1, lastname = "mike", genderid = 1 },
                new m_employees{ employeeid = 2, lastname = "jeni", genderid = 2 }
            };


            var x = from emp in Items
                join sex in genders
                    on emp.genderid equals sex.id
                    into a
                from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty(new m_genders())
                select new
                {
                    emp.lastname,
                    emp.genderid,
                    sex = b.title
                };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried using a mirror class (I created an Employee class and , not the auto generated m_employees and m_genders, and it worked fine. so the problem is in the auto-generated classes